# how to code my multipage to select a worksheet based on the multipage selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to code my mutlipage userform to select a certain worksheet based on the multipage section. I seem to be stuck there. Would someone happen to know the correct way to fix this problem? this is my last attempt that did not work.
Thank You,Steve

```
    Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
        Select Case MultiPage1.Value
            Case Page0
                Workbooks("Enova")Sheets.Activate
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks("Enova").Sheets(1).Activate` or `Workbooks("Enova").Sheets("sheetName").Activate`  provided your workbook is already active - if not you first need to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution. `MultiPage.Value` returns the index of the page, so `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. Use the below. You will need to specify, as per @Tim Williams comment, which workbook/sheet you want to select.

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    Select Case MultiPage1.Value
        Case 0
            Workbooks("Enova").Sheets(1).Activate 'This may not be correct, need more information
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: yes,i have tried that as well. I get an out of range error. The problem is that i have 4 order worksheets and 4 multipage pages. My multipages do not switch to the worksheet that i need them to. Rather it selects the worksheet that the workbook opens to, and i do not want the worksheets to be visible. Thank you very much for looking at it for me:)

Comment: I think you need to expand on your question then. The above will work if the workbook and worksheet specified exists in the workbook. It seems like you were looking for more than that though. Your question never specifies anything about the worksheets not being visible.